# Change baseline y to 1 in barplot (instead of zero)

Tags: r

I want to present a barplot with baseline y=1. I want to present fold change, therefore starting with 1. How do I change y starting value with the function barplot? Thanks!

```
a <- c(0.5,1.5)
barplot(a)
```

Comment: What about `barplot(a[a >= 1])`?

Comment: @jay.sf, thanks for your answer, but it doesnt seem to work...

Comment: I am not sure about your data, you don't only have two FC? But see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74100241/6574038) below for an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could subset on values greater than or equal to 1, use `ylim` together with `xpd`. This 1. does not show FC < 1 and the plot has baseline at 1.

```
barplot(a[a >= 1], ylim=c(1, max(a)*1.1), xpd=FALSE)
box()
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(334322)
a <- runif(10, 0, 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simulate a new y axis baseline by subtracting 1 and then compensating in the axis labels.

```r
a <- c(0.5,1.5)
at <- c(-0.5, 0, 0.5, 1)

barplot(a - 1, yaxt = "n")
axis(2, at = at, labels = at + 1)
abline(h = 0)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The direct solution is

```
barplot(a - 1, offset = 1)
```

[image]

Although, being fold changes, consider whether it may be better to use log2 scales or transformations.